# Divide/Split an array into two arrays one with even numbers and other with odd numbers

Tags: php

Please see my script, and identify the issue. Trying to Split an array into two arrays by value even or odd without built-in functions in PHP

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$length = count($array);
$even = array();
for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++){
  if($array[$i]/2 == 0){
     $even[] = $array[$i];
  }
  else{
     $odd[] = $array[$i];
  }
}
print_r($even);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($odd);
?>

current output
Array ( )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 )
```

Comment: The first example on [php.net's `array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) looks like what you need if you are intending to use built in functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in `if` condition, you want to check if the number is odd or even, you have to use modulus `%` operator. So your code becomes like this

```
<?php $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$length = count($array);
$even = array();
for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++){
  if($array[$i]%2 == 0){
$even[] = $array[$i];
}
else{
  $odd[] = $array[$i];
}
}
print_r($even);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($odd);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the modulo `%` operator when you check for even numbers. It gets the `remainder` when you divide your value by `2`.

`if($array[$i] % 2 == 0)`

Your current code `divides` your value by `2` then gets the `quotient`, that's why it doesn't equate to `0`. `2/2 = 1` `4/2 = 2` and so on...

Hope this helps.